# ListView animations, bug in Expandable Cells from DevBytes (glitch)

Tags: android, listview, animation, expandablelistview

I am trying to implement a listview where you can expand the cells (with a expanding/collapse animation), animation when delete a row, animation when add a row, etc. I thought it would be easy but all the external libraries I tried, they gave me problems.

So I realized there are some official videos from Google where they explain and give us code for this kind of animations, example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwE61B56pVQ (DevBytes: ListView Expanding Cells Animation). But in this video I have the first problems!!! At first point it works nice, looks like the Clock app from Android 4.4 (I don't know if I can find the code of this app somewhere).

So, this ListView Cells Animation has a very nice animation, and it scrolls very good when something is expanded. The problem is when you have a listview which few elements (and the listview doesn't fit all the screen). **I made a video to show that**:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-j0BXPyB2c0

I know that some guy tried to fix it here: https://gist.github.com/jgilfelt/7342135 . But it is still not working properly in some cases (there is the glitch or bad movements).

Seems to be that the part of the code that need to be fixed (I think, not sure) is:

```
/**
 * Calculates the top and bottom bound changes of the selected item. These values are
 * also used to move the bounds of the items around the one that is actually being
 * expanded or collapsed.
 *
 * This method can be modified to achieve different user experiences depending
 * on how you want the cells to expand or collapse. In this specific demo, the cells
 * always try to expand downwards (leaving top bound untouched), and similarly,
 * collapse upwards (leaving top bound untouched). If the change in bounds
 * results in the complete disappearance of a cell, its lower bound is moved is
 * moved to the top of the screen so as not to hide any additional content that
 * the user has not interacted with yet. Furthermore, if the collapsed cell is
 * partially off screen when it is first clicked, it is translated such that its
 * full contents are visible. Lastly, this behaviour varies slightly near the bottom
 * of the listview in order to account for the fact that the bottom bounds of the
 * actual listview cannot be modified.
 */
private int[] getTopAndBottomTranslations(int top, int bottom, int yDelta,
                                          boolean isExpanding) {
    int yTranslateTop = 0;
    int yTranslateBottom = yDelta;

    int height = bottom - top;

    if (isExpanding) {
        boolean isOverTop = top < 0;
        boolean isBelowBottom = (top + height + yDelta) > getHeight();
        if (isOverTop) {
            yTranslateTop = top;
            yTranslateBottom = yDelta - yTranslateTop;
        } else if (isBelowBottom){
            int deltaBelow = top + height + yDelta - getHeight();
            yTranslateTop = top - deltaBelow < 0 ? top : deltaBelow;
            yTranslateBottom = yDelta - yTranslateTop;
        }
    } else {
        int offset = computeVerticalScrollOffset();
        int range = computeVerticalScrollRange();
        int extent = computeVerticalScrollExtent();
        int leftoverExtent = range-offset - extent;

        boolean isCollapsingBelowBottom = (yTranslateBottom > leftoverExtent);
        boolean isCellCompletelyDisappearing = bottom - yTranslateBottom < 0;

        if (isCollapsingBelowBottom) {

            yTranslateTop = yTranslateBottom - leftoverExtent;
            yTranslateBottom = yDelta - yTranslateTop;
        } else if (isCellCompletelyDisappearing) {
            yTranslateBottom = bottom;
            yTranslateTop = yDelta - yTranslateBottom;
        }
    }

    return new int[] {yTranslateTop, yTranslateBottom};
}
```

Anybody has an idea? It is a pity to not be able to use that code due this bug.

Comment: Anybody? It really seems weird to me that it can't be solved.

Comment: Is there a fix for it ?

Comment: Came here looking for a fix.